# C# Send Commands

Tags: c#, command-line

I have a command line program running and I would like to send additional commands to it (I.E. Once it is already running)
How can I do this in C#?

Comment: Is it expecting commands to be sent to it? Does it listening for it? Need more information on your command line program you have developed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the process is started by your C# program, then you can use [Process.StandardInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx) to send commands to it.

If you are sending command to other processes, you can use the SendKey class as demoed in [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SendKeys.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

A few possibilities:

- [Handling Messages in Console Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163417.aspx)
- [How to send command to console application from GUI application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015388/how-to-send-command-to-console-application-from-gui-application)
- [How can I send keypresses to a running process object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686865/how-can-i-send-keypresses-to-a-running-process-object) (from @Truewill)

Comment: Or optionally [How can I send keypresses to a running process object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686865/how-can-i-send-keypresses-to-a-running-process-object)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about an interactive console program you just need to use Console.Readline() to get the input from the console and process it in your code. If you are talking about something more complex read about Inter-process communication (IPC).