# C# measuring copy time thought windows explorer

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a function that copies a file or a folder and measures the copy time

```
 public static TimeSpan CopyFileExplorer(string filePath, string fileDestination)
    {

        string command = @"/select, " + filePath;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", command);
        SendKeys.Send("^(C)");
        command = @"/select, " + fileDestination;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe",command);
        DateTime startCopy = DateTime.Now;
        SendKeys.Send("^(V)"); 

        //need to be catched when explorer finishes the copy
        DateTime endCopy = DateTime.Now;

        return endCopy - startCopy;
    }
```

I have tried to find when the "copy window" of explorer disappears, but I didn't succeed...

Comment: any reason you do not use `File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName)`?

Comment: I need to use windows explorer ...and perform the like the user

Comment: Why? still don't get it, there will be never ever a reason to use something like that and it is very bad practice to send key commands around out of your forms application and open an explorer window...

Comment: @Ela One valid argument would be that copying through Explorer allows copying to locations that aren't simple directories (ZIP files, FTP servers, etc.). That still wouldn't require sending keys to other processes, but it would be a reason to not use `File.Copy`. (I think [`IFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would be the right way to go, but I'm not entirely sure.)

Comment: I know that this is an awful way... and mo one will copy a file in such a way... My goal is to perform the copy of the files like a regular user using the windows explorer and measure the time it takes

Comment: @milkana maybe read about other ways to do it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647447/send-folder-rename-command-to-windows-explorer and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400419/c-sharp-send-commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't get the reason why you would ever do some awful stuff like that

you should try `SendKeys.SendWait("");`

Regarding the solution to send ctrl+c, ctrl+v to the explorer window, here are some other threads about how to use the explorer:

[Send Folder Rename Command to Windows Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647447/send-folder-rename-command-to-windows-explorer)

[C# Send Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400419/c-sharp-send-commands)