# Passing arguments at run time for a background application in delphi

Tags: delphi, user-interface, delphi-7, pascal

im coding a program that starts an command prompt boot application ,at run time of the boot application,the boot application asks many questions like for eg.press 1 to read or 2 to write.but always i'll be reading from the app.i always want to pass 2 to it.but the issue is how should i know that the back ground boot application has asked me a question and that i should reply with appropriate answer dynamically?

Comment: Use a redirect to redirect an input file of your making to stdin of the process.

Comment: See here how set up a two way communication with a console application: [How to send command to console application from GUI application](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2015388/576719).

Comment: What is a 'boot application'?

Comment: Have you considered using Perl? What you've requested is exactly what the [`Expect`](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect/Expect.pod) library provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the program reads the input from the standard input then you can create a text file containing your input:

```
2
```

Then redirect the standard input to that file:

myapp.exe < inputfile.txt

Perhaps the program  has command line options that would also allow you to avoid being prompted.

Note that your question is ambigous. If you are choosing the option to read, shouldn't you input 1?